# switching to ramdisk root

Tags: ramdisk

My application is to do a secure erase on my system disk (an SSD) using hdparm
from a shell script. So my thoughts were:

1. create a ramdisk
2. copy the linux OS to the ramdisk
3. unmount the original system drive
4. do a secure erase

I created the ramdisk and mounted it, but when I do a pivot_root, it can't find any of the applications. I copied all of /bin and /sbin to the ramdisk.

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use DBAN?  Any time you're trying to do something that involves security rolling your own can be dangerous.

Comment: Aren't the applications in `/usr`?

Comment: I am not sure DBAN would work. This application is on an autonomous vehicle that decides it needs to self destruct. No Human control Also DBAN does NOT do a secure erase.